# validate model using MOQ

Tags: c#, moq

I have a model (sample below) and would like to validate using MOQ.

```
public class Employee{

 public string FirstName {get;set;}
 public string LastName {get;set;}

}
```

Would like to run following test cases

1. FirstName and LastName is not empty
2. FirstName and LastName input length is not > 50 chars

To be honest, I do not know anything about MOQ at all and thus did not try any option yet.

Comment: MOQ is not a validation library. For something like that, you will want a package like FluentValidation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moq is used in unit testing, it is used to mock fack instances to the system under test object,

You can validate object by implementing `IValidatableObject`,

Try below code snippet,

```
public class Employee : IValidatableObject
{

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName) || FirstName.Length > 50) {
            results.Add(new ValidationResult("Invalid first Name"));
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName) || LastName.Length > 50)
        {
            results.Add(new ValidationResult("Invalid last Name"));
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

To validate object ,

```
 var toValidate = new Employee(){};

 var results = new List<ValidationResult>();


 bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(
        toValidate,
        new ValidationContext(toValidate, null, null),
        results,
        true);
```